# c# Displaying the size of a File in kB in a Label

Tags: c#, file, size, label, fileinfo

hi guys wonder if anyone can help me with this problem, I've been playing with c# for a few weeks now so I'm still a bit of a virgin, the issue I have been having is with the fileinfo constructor, I would like to display the size of a file in kb's in a label underneath the image/audio file/video file (I am building a basic media player), here is the code i have so far on this issue:

public void GetFileSize(String FileName)
        {

```
        FileInfo fs = new FileInfo (FileName);
        long filesize = FileName.Length / 1024;

        /*string filesize = System.Convert.ToString(size);*/
        picFileSizeLabel.Text = System.Convert.ToString(filesize);


    }
```

For some reason the label only displays 0, when I change it to "long filesize = FileName.Length" and don't divide by 1024 I get a 51 or sometimes 55 displayed in the label, any help or comments will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :**  You are trying to get the `FileName Length` instead of `File Length`

**Solution1**
This :

```
 long filesize = FileName.Length / 1024;
```

Should be:

```
 long filesize = fs.Length / 1024;
```

finally it should look like :

```
FileInfo fs = new FileInfo (FileName);
long filesize = fs.Length / 1024;
```

**Solution 2:**  to add `KB` at the end of `filesize`

```
picFileSizeLabel.Text = System.Convert.ToString(filesize)+"KB";
```

Comment: Thanks!! that helped a lot it works fine now, now I just have to display it in kb

Comment: @user3014192: Okay .Length gives you in bytes so if you do /1024 you will get KB right?

Comment: Yeah it works fine and displays the file size in kb perfectly, I would just like it to say "826kb" instead of just "826",

Comment: @user3014192: check my edited answer with Solution 2 section and accept it as answer if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice you have been a great help, solution 2 works fine

Comment: @user3014192: You are Welcome :) I'm glad to be help of you.